# add yahoo mail to android phone having two step verification active?

Tags: email, 2-step-verification, yahoo-mail

Any help?

I want to get rid of the lousy Yahoo app on android. it has a lot of problems regarding notifications..

But when I try to add yahoo account in the Android-Email app, it says:

Login failed:
Possible reasons: Two-step verification is enabled for your Yahoo email. Login to .... disable it...
:(

Comment: Try the web interface instead of the app to regain access. It should give you some other way to gain access in absence of two factor authentication.

Comment: Do you actually have two-step verification turned on for yahoo?

Comment: yes i do have it on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most other 2FA implementations, Yahoo also supports "App Passwords" for apps and APIs which do not have a proper login system to authorize the 2-factor login.
These are static passwords which work as if there's no 2FA implemented at all. Be sure to never share such password with anybody as it bypasses the 2FA.

Yahoo has detailed steps to generate the App Passwords. So, follow the steps to get started:

1. Sign in and go to your Account security page.
2. Click Generate app password or Manage app passwords.
3. Select your app from the drop-down menu and click Generate.
4. Follow the instructions below the password.
5. Click Done.
6. Use this app password and your email address to sign in to your email app.

For more details, visit the Yahoo website - https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN15241.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Outlook, it works with two-step verification.

Comment: You've tried it with Yahoo's two-step verification? The fact that it works with MS two-step doesn't mean it works with Yahoo two-step.